# Filter two columns by one property

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `WHERE` that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Tasks t WHERE (@search IS NULL OR (t.TaskId LIKE '%' + @search + '%'))
```

Here im searching all records that matching `@search` property in `t.TaskId`.

Now, i want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Tasks t WHERE (@search IS NULL OR (t.TaskId LIKE '%' + @search + '%'))
                            AND (@search IS NULL OR (t.ProjectId LIKE '%' + @search + '%'))
```

I want to serch records that match `@search` checking `TaskId` and then `ProjectId` but for now its not working.

How to filter two columns in query by one property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
SELECT * FROM Tasks t 
WHERE (@search IS NULL OR (t.TaskId LIKE '%' + @search + '%'))
   OR (@search IS NULL OR (t.ProjectId LIKE '%' + @search + '%'))
   ^^------------------here
```

or shorter:

```
SELECT * FROM Tasks t 
WHERE @search IS NULL 
OR 
(
   t.TaskId LIKE '%' + @search + '%' OR
   t.ProjectId LIKE '%' + @search + '%'
)
```

Comment: If you only have `or` conditions, you don't need the parenthesis...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
 SELECT * FROM Tasks t WHERE @search IS NULL OR( t.TaskId LIKE '%' + @search + '%' and 
 t.ProjectId LIKE '%' + @search + '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are not going to be used for `LIKE` in this case, so you could just use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Tasks t
WHERE t.TaskId LIKE '%' + COALESCE(@search, '') + '%') AND
      t.ProjectId LIKE '%' + COALESCE(@search, '') + '%');
```

Or, equivalently, you can use `CONCAT()` (which ignores `NULL` in SQL Server):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Tasks t
WHERE t.TaskId LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%') AND
      t.ProjectId LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%');
```

Answer (score 1):

With the wildcards at the front and back you may want to try PATINDEX with IIF:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tasks t 
WHERE PATINDEX(IIF(@search IS NULL, '', '%' + @search + '%'), t.TaskId) > 0
OR PATINDEX(IIF(@search IS NULL, '', '%' + @search + '%'), t.ProjectId) > 0
```

Alternatively, you can also prepare the @search variable beforehand to make the query cleaner:

```
SET @search = IIF(@search IS NULL, '', '%' + @search + '%')

SELECT * 
FROM Tasks t 
WHERE PATINDEX(@search, t.TaskId) > 0
OR PATINDEX(@search, t.ProjectId) > 0
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15